# Symfony2 Ajax not initiating at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a script that increases an arrays value by 1 everytime I click a button. It seems like an easy task and im sure the function itself is working. However the ajax part is not initializing at all, but the jQuery before ajax is working... Since im no expert in ajax I bet the problem is somewhere in the script.

So this is the simple twig:

```
   <tbody class="test">      

         {% if product is defined %}

              {% for info in product %}

                <tr>

                  <td> <img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/6.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

                  <td>{{ info.model }}</td>
                  <td>

                  {% for key, item in cart %}



                    <div class="input-append">

                    <input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" value="{{ item }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="{{ key }}"/>
                    <button class="btn" type="button"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a></button>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>

                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for key in cart|keys %}

                    {% if key == info.id %}

                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>

                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                  </td>

                  <td>{{ info.price }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.discount }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.value }}</td>


                  <td>{{ info.getFinal|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>


                </tr>


 {% endfor %}
```

My script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".test").on('click', '.plus', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
        alert("product id " + $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id') + " Quantity " + $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val())
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: /cart/update,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),
                quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == false) {
                    alert('error')
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/cart/update", name="cart_update")
 */
public function cartUpdateAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric and exists in your db etc*/
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric etc */
    /** if all is good then put your logic*/
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Now the JQuery part is working ant the alert is showing me the id and quantity of the product. But after that nothing happens. And in the little Symfony2 toolbar at the bottom of the page, where the ajax requests should be displayed im just getting that there are no ajax requests yet.. any ideas?

**BIG UPDATE**

Looks like I fixed all of the bugs, since I am not getting any more errors in the profiler, however I am still getting the same problem. The Ajax is just not doing anything.
This is what I changed:

I changed the url of the script and removed the `async:false` since Its not really needed here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.plus', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update/cart',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }
        }
    });
});
});
```

After the route change I got a new error, that the em is not defined in the update controller so I added one more line:

```
public function updateAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric and exists in your db etc*/
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];/** first put all validations not empty/ is numeric etc */
    /** if all is good then put your logic*/
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  /// the line I added.
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

And I added the POST requirement in my routing(I dont know is it needed, but I saw this in other examples):

```
update_cart:
  pattern:  /update/cart
  defaults: { _controller: MpShopBundle:Homepage:update }
  requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

Now the profiler is not showing any errors, and my route is fixed(I am getting: `POST http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart`, and the updateAction ). But the Ajax is still not working... I dont understand...

I just realised that I am not getting GET methods now, only POST.. Why is that?

```
a59e68  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:36 +0200
32c2e1  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:35 +0200
6ec8ff  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:33 +0200
4ac156  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:32 +0200
04c5a1  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:31 +0200
968789  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:29 +0200
c8372b  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:28 +0200
97192f  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:29:26 +0200
dff8a3  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:20:47 +0200
e4177b  ::1 POST    http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/update/cart   Wed, 06 May 2015 14:20:46 +0200
```

Comment: Url part should be quoted with string `'/cart/update'`

Comment: I quoted the string but I have the same problem..

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in symfony profiler? (You can click "View last 10" and try to find your ajax request)

Comment: @MaxLipsky Hey, I am getting something, but I dont know what they mean. I updated my post, check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've solved your first issue by registering the path in routing.yml, but you introduced a small issue with the update

Based on your second update, you can see that your application is having trouble finding the path:

```
http://localhost/Digidis/tree/web/app_dev.php/%7B%7Bpath('update_cart')%7D%7D
```

which url decoded, becomes:

```
{{path('update_cart')}}
```

The solution is that your $.ajax JS line which currently reads:

```
url: "{{path('update_cart')}}",
```

Should read

```
url: "/cart/update/",
```

This is because unfortunately you cannot use twig markup in JS fiels

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I did that too, however I am still not getting Ajax request. I updated my post. Check it out please!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about saying the AJAX is still not working? If you open your network tab in the developer console, do you see the ajax request go through? Do you get a 200 response if it does go through?

Comment: So this means your AJAX is working, and all of your code is functioning. If you say the AJAX is not working, I would guess you mean that the intended result is not appearing, rather than the AJAX not working. This might be because you are not saving the cart back to the session in your PHP after you increase the count for the productId, so it is always defaulting to the empty array() you initialise if the session cannot find the cart